# Flutter Bloc pattern question from The complete developers guide course Udemy 165

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a question about this course in Udemy where Im trying to set up Bloc pattern for authentication in Flutter. The problem is that I get a null value from start and also later when I type a required '@' from the snapshot.error of the StreamBuilder. It's set up so I should get an error message until I type in a '@' and then the message should go away. I have three relevant files: loginscreen, bloc and validators. What do you guys think can go wrong here?

Loginscreen:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          emailField(),
          passwordField(),
          //const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
          Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0)),
          submitButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField() {
    //Listener for streams rebuilds builder function when found

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.email,
        //snapshot contains the value from the stream
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String>? snapshot) {
          return TextField(
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              print(newValue);
              bloc.changeEmail(newValue);
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'you@example.com',
              labelText: 'Email Address',
              //This is null for some reason. Something is not right here
              //First it shows error because no @ and when pressed I get null
              errorText: snapshot!.error.toString(),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

Bloc:

class Bloc with Validators {
  //We are working with Strings in the Streamcontrollers (marked with String type)
  final _email = StreamController<String>();
  final _password = StreamController<String>();

  //Annotation with generic type in front. Not required though
  // Add data to stream (access to stream)
  // Apply the validation transform created
  Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Stream<String> get password => _password.stream.transform(validatePassword);

  // Change data (access to sink)
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _email.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _password.sink.add;

  dispose() {
    _email.close();
    _password.close();
  }
}

final bloc = Bloc();

Validators:

class Validators {
  final validateEmail =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    if (email.contains('@')) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Enter a valid email!');
    }
  });

  final validatePassword = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (password, sink) {
    if (password.length > 7) {
      sink.add(password);
    } else {
      sink.addError('You must be at least 8 characters!');
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

[image]

After change to:

errorText: snapshot?.error?.toString() ?? snapshot?.data,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are always reading the stream's error here:

```dart
    errorText: snapshot!.error.toString(),
```

but you only add errors in this else:

```
    if (email.contains('@')) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Enter a valid email!');
    }
```

You may try to replace how this value is read by:

```
              //This is null for some reason. Something is not right here
              //First it shows error because no @ and when pressed I get null
              errorText: snapshot?.error?.toString() ?? snapshot?.data,
```

In this way, if there is no error, `errorText` will get stream's data.

Update:
If you want to make this message completely go alway after an @ be inserted, you may first take a look on how errorText works. From Flutter`s InptuDecorator source code:

```
  /// Text that appears below the [InputDecorator.child] and the border.
  ///
  /// If non-null, the border's color animates to red and the [helperText] is
  /// not shown.
  ///
  /// In a [TextFormField], this is overridden by the value returned from
  /// [TextFormField.validator], if that is not null.
  final String? errorText;
```

So, this message will be hidden if you not pass a String to it. What is happening in this code here:

```
    errorText: snapshot!.error.toString(),
```

Is something like this: `null.toString();`. Dart can and will parse null to string and it will be transformed in a string having `null` as content.
To fix this, we add an `?` mark after the error, like this:  `snapshot?.error?.toString(),`. Now, `toString()` will only be invoked if `error` is not null.

Tip: do explore the source code of the widgets that you are using. They are widely commented and you can get information much faster than google random things

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tales Barreto! Yes I tried that solution and it worked, sort of one problem still though is that the text comes in red instead of blue (like error text) even if the @ is there. I guess thats because the error text is null and he reads from snapshot.data from there.

Comment: Hey! I just updated my answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, thank you for the insight! I have read that documentation and I think the problem is that when you begin typing it goes to else (the error message is set) after pressing @ the error becomes null instead (but is still in error) and the snapshot?.data is set to errorText and when I type every caracter is seen now until I delete @ and error message is seen again (always in red if I dont removes all). This is something I have a little trouble wrapping my head around!